# Not printing anything after for loop in a batch script

Tags: java, batch-file, asciidoctor-pdf

Below is my batch script which is not executing the line after for loop end. It's not print echo end or the line after that. The line `asciidoctor-pdf C:\Users\abc\Conversion_to_PDF\OutputFiles\*.adoc` is causing it. But I am not sure with what the problem is.

```
@echo off

echo # Starting job

java -jar C:\Users\abc\Conversion_to_PDF\swagger2markup-cli-1.3.1.jar convert -i C:\Users\abc\Conversion_to_PDF\HIP-ProviderManagement-1.0.0-swagger.json -d C:\Users\abc\Conversion_to_PDF\OutputFiles

chdir /d C:\Users\abc\Conversion_to_PDF\OutputFiles

for %%A in (*.adoc) do (
asciidoctor-pdf C:\Users\abc\Conversion_to_PDF\OutputFiles\*.adoc
echo %%A
)
echo # end
C:\Users\abc\Downloads\sejda-console-3.2.3\bin\sejda-console merge -f C:\Users\abc\Conversion_to_PDF\OutputFiles\*.pdf -o C:\Users\abc\Conversion_to_PDF\OutputFiles\merged.pdf
```

Comment: Comment `@echo off` and rerun the batch file, and see what errors you see on console. You might want to post them here in the question.

Comment: I did that but there's no error coming up on console. It just executes till for loop end, that's it.

Comment: I suppose that `asciidoctor-pdf` which Windows command interpreter finds somewhere in current directory or any directory listed in environment variable `PATH` and having a file extension listed in environment variable `PATHEXT` has as file extension `.bat` or `.cmd`, i.e. the executed file is a batch file. In this case you need the command __CALL__ to call the batch file from within your batch file. Run in a cmd prompt window `call /?` for help. Hint: Make your coding work easier and specify always a file executed or called from within a batch file with including also the file extension.

Comment: By the way: You run a __FOR__ loop to do something for each *.adoc file, but pass to `asciidoctor-pdf` a folder path with a wildcard pattern instead of the current *.adoc file name with full path. That does not make much sense. So most likely the __FOR__ loop should be `for %%A in (*.adoc) do call asciidoctor-pdf.bat "%%~fA"` or `for %%A in (*.adoc) do asciidoctor-pdf.exe "%%~fA"` depending on what `asciidoctor-pdf` really is.

Comment: It's a bat file and I added .bat extension to it in the batch script but it's still the same. I also tried "%%~fA" but no changes. adding Any more suggestions? I'm out of ideas!
How can I change it to a while loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
call asciidoctor-pdf ....
```

since `asciidoctor-pdf` is a batch file. The `call` means "execute this, then return to the next statement". Without the call, it means "go to this batchfile" and it is *not* told to return to the original (the "caller")